# encryption in spring-cloud-config-server

Tags: password-encryption, spring-cloud-config

I'm trying to run spring-cloud-config-server with an encrypted property in application.yml.

```
---

server:
  port: 8888  

spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: file:/Users/gadams/git/cs-config

encrypt:
  key-store:
    location: classpath:/config-server.jks
    password: password
    alias: alias
    secret: secret

security:
  user:
    password: '{cipher}encryptedPassword'
```

I get the following error on startup:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot decrypt: key=security.user.password
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.encrypt.EnvironmentDecryptApplicationInitializer.decrypt(EnvironmentDecryptApplicationInitializer.java:201) ~[spring-cloud-context-1.1.6.RELEASE.jar:1.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.encrypt.EnvironmentDecryptApplicationInitializer.decrypt(EnvironmentDecryptApplicationInitializer.java:165) ~[spring-cloud-context-1.1.6.RELEASE.jar:1.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.encrypt.EnvironmentDecryptApplicationInitializer.initialize(EnvironmentDecryptApplicationInitializer.java:95) ~[spring-cloud-context-1.1.6.RELEASE.jar:1.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener$DelegatingEnvironmentDecryptApplicationInitializer.initialize(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:333) ~[spring-cloud-context-1.1.6.RELEASE.jar:1.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.applyInitializers(SpringApplication.java:635) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:349) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at com.collegescheduler.ConfigServerApplication.main(ConfigServerApplication.java:12) [bin/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No decryption for FailsafeTextEncryptor. Did you configure the keystore correctly?
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.encrypt.EncryptionBootstrapConfiguration$FailsafeTextEncryptor.decrypt(EncryptionBootstrapConfiguration.java:152) ~[spring-cloud-context-1.1.6.RELEASE.jar:1.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.encrypt.EnvironmentDecryptApplicationInitializer.decrypt(EnvironmentDecryptApplicationInitializer.java:193) ~[spring-cloud-context-1.1.6.RELEASE.jar:1.1.6.RELEASE]
    ... 9 common frames omitted
```

I'm using org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Camden.SR3. How should one go about encrypting the spring-security user password in the config server?

Comment: Did you check my answer?

Answer (score 0):

It's something wrong in your keystore configuration from log.

Use `keytool` to verify the pass/secret/alias of your key store firstly.

Comment: The keystore config works fine for encrypted properties in the configuration from github. It doesn't work during bootstrap phase, for properties in the config server's application.yml.

Answer (score 0):

Did you respect the [prerequisites](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/spring-cloud-config.html#_encryption_and_decryption)?

> Prerequisites: to use the encryption and decryption features **you need
>   the full-strength JCE installed in your JVM (it’s not there by
>   default**). You can download the "Java Cryptography Extension (JCE)
>   Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files" from Oracle, and follow
>   instructions for installation (essentially replace the 2 policy files
>   in the JRE lib/security directory with the ones that you downloaded).

You should also have in your `pom.xml`:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-rsa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```